# Time complexity and memory limit of glm in R

Tags: r, time-complexity, glm

I want to use `glm( ... , family = "binomial")` to do a logistic regression with my big dataset which has 80,000,000 rows and 125 columns as a data.frame. But when I run in RStudio, it just crashes:

[image]

So I wonder what the time complexity of `glm()` is, and whether there are any solutions to handle such data? Someone suggested I try running the code from command line: does this make any difference (I tried, but it seems that doesn't work either)?

Comment: So is the problem here _time_ complexity, or running out of memory?

Comment: Sorry already change the title:)@Hong Ooi

Comment: For large datasets I'd recommend the `data.table` package in general. Although this won't help you solve your problem. Have a look at sparse matrices (package `Matrix`) which will work with glm too. Have you considered sampling subsets already?

Comment: I want to keep the original data as complete as possible so I haven't sample, but it's a solution anyway:) And the data is not sparse. I am wondering what's the max data size gym() can process

Comment: take a look at the [high performance task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) ?  Can you say specifically what "crashes down" means?

Comment: I have added an image for what happened

Comment: so ... what are the symptoms when you run the same code via `R CMD BATCH` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Memory requirement: R has to load the entire dataset into memory (RAM).  However, your dataset is (assuming entries are 32-bits) is roughly 37 gigabytes -- much larger than the amount of RAM you have on your computer.  Therefore, it crashes.  You cannot use R for this dataset unless you use some special big data packages, and I'm not sure it's even feasible then.

There are other languages do not need to load it into memory to look at it, and so it might be wise to do that.

2. Time complexity for GLMs: if N = # of observations (usually # of rows), and p = # of variables (usually # of columns), it is O(p^3 + Np^3) for most standard GLM algorithms.

For your situation, it has a time complexity of approximately 10^12 which is still barely in the realm of possibility, but you probably need more than one modern PC running for at least a few days.

Comment: Do you have any reference that mentions the O(p^3 + Np^3) complexity for most standard GLM algorithms?